# I cannot send e-mail from DSpace

Tags: smtp, ssl-certificate, dspace

When I try to reset my password in DSpace in the XMLUI interface I get this error:

`sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

When I try to register I get this error:

`Unable to send email to this address.`

How can I get rid of this? I'm new to DSpace.

Comment: Are you the administrator of DSpace? If so, is email functioning correctly? Try ``[dspace-home]/bin/dspace test-email``.

Comment: Reason of this problem is about connecting to an SSL-protected email server. You can get an idea how to fix it from this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+to+SSL+services).

Comment: Please post following details in order to debug your problem: 1) mail.server.* properties from dspace.cfg 2) Output for the following two commands: echo "test" | mail -s "test subject" [hidden email] /dspace/bin/dspace dsrun org.dspace.core.Email